# Random Voltage Spikes Reading From ADS1115

Tags: operational-amplifier, raspberry-pi, data

so I have a pcb circuit that uses a Raspberry Pi, ADS1115, BME280, and a TGS6810 sensor to detect natural gases. The circuit seems to work perfectly and I am able to see clear curves when I plot the data from the ADS. The only issue is that the ADS will read random voltage spikes from the sensor/op amp and I'm really not sure why. My first thought was maybe my capacitors/resistors or even the ground lines are adding some noise to the circuit but I'm really not sure. I'm also just not sure where to even begin debugging something like this. Has anybody experienced something similar or maybe has input to what I should investigate first? Also, the 3V leading to the TGS6810 is from a TLV757P 3V voltage regulator and it supplies a very consistent 3V to the circuit, so I do not think it is a fluctuating input voltage issue.

A quick-drawn schematic of the circuit can be seen below:
[image]

Here is an image of the voltage spikes I am referring to:
[image]

Lastly, here is a code snippet of the function that I am using to gather this data. It's unlikely that this code is the issue as I have used this code for a TGS2611 sensor circuit without issues.

```
def dataCollect(self):
        epochTimeStamp = (int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%s')))
        temp = BME280.read_temperature()
        humidity = BME280.read_humidity()
        CH4_V_Left = self.adc1.read_adc(0, gain=self.gain) * 125e-6
        CH4_V_Right = self.adc1.read_adc(1, gain=self.gain) * 125e-6
        print(("Temp: {}\nHumidity: {}\nCH4_L: {}\nCH4_R: {}\nTime Elapsed: {}\n\n").format("{:.02f}".format(temp), "{:.02f}".format(humidity), "{:.06f}".format(CH4_V_Left), "{:.06f}".format(CH4_V_Right),self.timesince))

        data = temp, humidity ,CH4_V_Left, CH4_V_Right, epochTimeStamp
        return data
```

Comment: Those are BIG spikes.  Looks less like analog noise and more like a digital communication problem... either I2C errors or reading a FIFO when it is empty.  Can you see if the reading is exactly all-1s (FFFF) or do you not have access to the raw data before filtering and scaling are performed?

Comment: Are those chips in your design, or are you using ready-made modules? If your design, post schematics. If ready-made modules, post links to each and every module schematics and manuals please. Which I2C speed you are using? Which values of pull-up resistors are on the I2C bus (and how many and where they are)? Are you directly connecting a 3.3V I2C bus to chip with 5V supply that can barely read 3.3V as logic 1?

Comment: It should be easily to isolate if Vout is clean to verify if data is valid or even ready.

Comment: Why is ALERT pin grounded against datasheet suggestions? So yes, multiple reasons why communication on I2C might be broken. Do you even check return codes if I2C transactions succeed or fail, or assume that they return good data always?

Comment: “Is it sync’d to acquisition? If not use burst mode.

Comment: @Justme basically the ADS would not work at all if the alrt, addr, A2, A3 pins were not grounded. Not sure why and I don't quite remember what error codes were being thrown. I have it on a pcb that has them grounded so I don't have a way to test them. Also, regarding your other question, the entire schematic is designed by me with the help of documentation. None of it is module other than the ADS , BME280, and Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Yes, testing the Vout output is the very next thing I was going to try. I'm not sure what you mean by "sync'd acquisition" though. How would I change it to burst mode?

Comment: @LukeyP That is also very suspicious. Would you please post the schematics of the PCB to see what's wrong with it?

Comment: @BenVoigt That is a very good observation actually. I had not considered that. I don't have access to the raw data, or at least I don't know how to access it. I wonder if I could write some code to detect the possible I2C errors?

Comment: @LukeyP: I'd definitely recommend also capturing the I2C traffic on a logic analyzer or an I2C bus capture device.  At my office we use the [TotalPhase Aardvark](https://www.totalphase.com/products/aardvark-i2cspi/) but there are cheaper options such as the $30 "Bus Pirate v3", [instructions for I2C capture here](https://www.digitalpeer.com/blog/sniffing-i2c-traffic-with-a-bus-pirate)

Comment: @BenVoigt Aardvark is good if you know the I2C bus protocol and timing and transactions themselves are fine, but there is problems in the data the transactions contain. A logic analyzer could be better to see glitches, violations in the protocol and timing. Which is also no match for a 2-channel oscilloscope to see issues like too weak pull-up resistors or invalid voltage levels due to mismatching 5V and 3.3V devices on same bus (like I suspect is the case here).